# Are there International Quidditch Tournaments?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, I found this:

> 'That Quidditch Cup'll have our name on it this year,' said Wood happily as they trudged back up to the castle. 'I wouldn't be surprised if you turn out better than Charlie Weasley, and **he could have played for England** if he hadn't gone off chasing dragons.'

Did Wood really mean that there was an International Quidditch tournament something like Quidditch World Cup? Has the canon mentions it anywhere else?

Comment: I suspect you have not yet finished the series. Keep reading, my friend.

Comment: Hah, not sure how big of a spoiler it would count as ^^; but, yes, it is mentioned elsewhere (and the fact that Wood said it pretty much proves it anyways) :-)

Comment: I don't think the canon mentions an international Quidditch tournament other than the World Cup, although *Quidditch Through the Ages* also mentions an international broom race (in Sweden, iirc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Quidditch World Cup is the gold standard international Quidditch match.

From the [*Harry Potter* Lexicon on the Quidditch World Cup stadium specs](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/quidditch/world_cup.html):

> The Ministry of Magic spent a year magically constructing a huge stadium on Dartmoor (Pm) for the Quidditch World Cup in August, 1994.
>
> - approach through a wood
>
>   - a twenty-minute walk along a lantern-lit trail
>   - immense gold walls
>   - ten cathedrals would fit comfortably inside it
>   - seats 100,000 people
>   - Ministry task force of 500 worked on it for a year
>   - Muggle-Repelling Charms on every inch of it
>   - Top Box provides the prime seats: about 20 purple and gilt chairs
>   - large parchment tickets
>   - located on Dartmoor (Pm)
>   - a "nice, deserted moor." (GF6)
>   - stagger the arrivals: people with cheap tickets had to arrive two
>       weeks early
>   - a few use Muggle transport to get there, but most use Portkeys or
>       Apparate.
>   - two hundred Portkeys around Britain
>   - suffused with a mysterious golden light which seems to come from the
>       stadium itself
>   - giant blackboard opposite Top Box which is a score board and also
>       shows advertising
>   - velvet-covered, tasseled programs
>
> There is some inconsistency in dates with the World Cup. In GF8, Ludo Bagman welcomes everyone to the "four hundred and twenty second Quidditch World Cup". However, Quidditch through the Ages sets forth the history of the World Cup competition. It says that the Cup was first held in 1473, and held every 4 years since. That means that the Cup had been held around 130 times by 1994. Not even close to 422.
>   Also, if the Cup has been held every four years from 1473, then 1993 and 1997 would have been Cup-years, not 1994. However, the Quidditch World Cup of 1877 is known as The Tournament Nobody Remembers because, for reasons unknown, no one has any recollection of the matches taking place (thought they undoubtedly did). Therefore, the Tournament was restaged in 1878, and from then on the World Cup was held every four years from the new date (Pm).

Comment: In which book, can I find this?

Comment: most of this is from the 4th book.

Comment: @SachinShekhar -- If you go to the link I provided, each entry is annotated with which book the entry is from, or whether it's from Pottermore (pm). :)

Comment: How much would it cost to build a real world multinational Quidditch sports?

Comment: you would first need to get 14 real world magical flying brooms

Comment: @SachinShekhar -- Oh, man. How much would it cost? Uh ... I'm bad at maths! Yeah, that's it! ;)

Comment: @user13267 Not a big deal when we have got EmDrive (NASA's Impossible Engine). I am already working on it.